# How can I teach Gmail to warn me that the subject is empty

Tags: gmail

Gmail sends your email without any notification when the subject is empty. I read that in the past this was a feature. It's really annoying to send a work email message without a subject.

So has anyone a solution like a browser add-on or a script that prevents you to send an email without noticing that the subject is empty?

Comment: [This person had the opposite problem](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/4538/can-i-stop-gmail-from-warning-me-i-have-no-subject?rq=1), and it seems like Gmail stopped doing it circa 2012.

Comment: Yeah it would have been great if they added a toggle option for that so the user could choose and not remove it entirely.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no setting for that, and a quick perusal of the Chrome Web Store didn't offer up any likely prospects.

Comment: A script can't prevent a user from sending a message.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm afraid that no, with the standard Gmail client, there's no way to get it to warn you when the subject is empty. There also doesn't appear to be any Chrome extensions which fill this niche, either.

What's frustrating is that Gmail used to have this feature, but seems to have removed it circa 2012.

Your best bet would be to use Gmail's "Undo Send" feature in case you do happen to send a message without a subject, but that does depend on you noticing in no more than 30 seconds.

Comment: Too bad Google removed this. The pro version of Gmail allows for blocking subject-less messages.

Comment: Dear Jean-Rene:  (My school gives me access to G Suite for Education, which might qualify as the pro version of Gmail.)  Where's the setting to block subject-less messages in the pro version of Gmail?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, for now. I suppose some people complained about it, and the Gmail team removed it.

BUT, you and everyone else who wants it can ask them to bring it back ***as an option***.

In Gmail, click on the setting (cogwheel) icon, then "Send feedback".

Answer (score -1):

There is a Chrome extension that will show a warning if you try to send an email in Gmail without a Subject: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gmail-empty-subject-check/jkbfdfpkfboepnfgjfhldginhpcgpjpe